# WCF Named Pipe IPC

Tags: wcf, named-pipes, netnamedpipebinding

I have been trying to get up to speed on Named Pipes this week.  The task I am trying to solve with them is that I have an existing windows service that is acting as a device driver that funnels data from an external device into a database.  Now I have to modify this service and add an optional user front end (on the same machine, using a form of IPC) that can monitor the data as it passes between the device and the DB as well as send some commands back to the service.

My initial ideas for the IPC were either named pipes or memory mapped files.  So far I have been working through the named pipe idea using [WCF Tutorial Basic Interprocess Communication](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wcf-tutorial-basic-interprocess-communication) .  My idea is to set the Windows service up with an additional thread that implements the WCF NamedPipe Service and use that as a conduit to the internals of my driver.

I have the sample code working, however I can not get my head around 2 issues that I am hoping that someone here can help me with:

1. In the tutorial the ServiceHost is instantiated with a typeof(StringReverser) rather than by referencing a concrete  class.  Thus there seems to be no mechanism for the Server to interact with the service itself (between the host.Open() and host.Close() lines).  Is it possible to create a link between and pass information between the server and the class that actually implements the service?  If so, how?
2. If I run a single instance of the server and then run multiple instance of the clients, it seems that each client gets a separate instance of the service class.  I tried adding some state information to the class implementing the service and it was only retained within the instance of the named pipe.  This is possibly related to the first question, but is there anyway to force the named pipes to use the same instance of the class that is implementing the service?
3. Finally, any thoughts on MMF vs Named Pipes?

**Edit - About the solution**

As per Tomasr's answer the solution lies in using the correct constructor in order to supply a concrete singleton class that implements the service ([ServiceHost Constructor (Object, Uri[])](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx)).  What I did not appreciate at the time was his reference to ensuring the service class was thread safe.  Naively just changing the constructor caused a crash in the server, and that ultimately lead me down the path of understanding InstanceContextMode from this blog entry [Instancecontextmode And Concurrencymode](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jsmith/archive/2006/05/16/instancecontextmode-and-concurrencymode.aspx). Setting the correct context nicely finished off the solution.

Comment: FYI the Instance Context blog link is dead.

Comment: As for Question #3, please refer to this blog post: http://techmikael.blogspot.com/2010/02/blazing-fast-ipc-in-net-4-wcf-vs.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For (1) and (2) the answer is simple: You can ask WCF to use a singleton instance of your service to handle all requests. Mostly all you need to do is use the alternate ServiceHost [constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms585487.aspx) that takes an Object instance instead of a type.

Notice, however, that you'll be responsible for making your service class thread safe.

As for 3, it really depends a lot on what you need to do, your performance needs, how many clients you expect at the same time, the amount of data you'll be moving and for how long it needs to be available, etc.

Comment: well that was a complete D'Oh now that you pointed the proper constructor out to me!  Thanks.  As for the performance, the final system will really only be one client to one server, but moving a moderate amount of data around.  I like the idea of the Named Pipe as a I can see how to set it up to move a structured object around, and it seems as if MMF is less structured.