# How to communicate between Windows Services

Tags: c#, wcf, service, windows-services, ipc

I have 2 windows services that I created using C#.

I would like one of the services to call a function in the second windows service.

How should I do it?

EDIT:

The issue is That I have to application that running ( I don't need them to be Rather service Process is good too) but I **need**  this 2 application to communicate, this 2 application are on the same server,

Comment: See [related post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/86286/175679) for cross-app communication.

Comment: Which kind of data? How many messages? What is average message size?

Answer (score 5):

Sure.  There are a bunch of IPC mechanisms you could use.  Remoting, TCP/HTTP Listeners, etc.

Does either service provide functionality that might be useful outside of the other service?

See this thread for more ideas:
[IPC Mechanisms in C# - Usage and Best Practices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56121/ipc-mechanisms-in-c-sharp-usage-and-best-practices)

EDIT: 
As Davide Piras pointed out, if WCF is available for you to use, then consider using it.  It will simplify life.  The WCF configuration files are sometimes a pain to wield, but there's a nice tool for that too:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms732009.aspx

Comment: Whenever possible remoting and HTTP should be avoided in favour of WCF

Answer (score 5):

Are the services on the same box? Do you have .NET 4? Highly recommend using the fastest mode possible, [memory-mapped files](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997372.aspx).

If they're on the same box, but you don't have .NET 4, or are in a homogenous Microsoft Windows network, [named pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) could work. More to the point, I'd use [WCF over a named pipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3066519/wcf-named-pipe-ipc).

Answer (score 4):

I found all the other answers correct but a little too much complicated (WCF is a big deal) and not scalable (memory and named pipes will only work on the same sever). I suggest you [DotNetMQ](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/193611/DotNetMQ-A-Complete-Message-Queue-System-for-NET) messaging system. It's easy to use and deploy and let's you communicate even between processes running on different servers.